# Is it appropriate to discretize conditional posteriors in an MCMC as an alternative to techniques like Metropolis-Hastings or slice-sampling?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, variational-bayes

**Background**

Suppose I am interested in sampling the posterior distribution defined by $p(\theta_1,\theta_2|y)$, where $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are parameters of interest and $y$ is a vector of observations. With proper priors $p(\theta_1)$ and $p(\theta_2)$, I set up my Gibbs sampler as follows:

1. Draw $\theta_1$ from a distribution with pdf proportional to $p(y|\theta_1,\theta_2)\times p(\theta_1)$
2. Draw $\theta_2$ from a distribution with pdf proportional to $p(y|\theta_1,\theta_2)\times p(\theta_2)$

I can repeat steps 1 and 2 to create a chain, and after some burn-in the cumulative distribution of draws should approach the posterior.

**Question**

When the conditional posteriors are not standard distributions, the typical approach is to use something like rejection sampling, slice sampling, Metropolis-Hastings or similar to conduct the sampling. Would it be reasonable instead to discretize the pdf via simple evaluation along a grid, normalize and draw from the resulting discrete distribution?

I know grid-search is valid in simple problems for the full-posterior, but I've never seen it applied to the conditional posteriors as above.

**Optional Context**

You might wonder why on earth I would do this. I'm actually working on a Variational-Bayes problem and the code is very performance sensitive- so the purpose of the discretization is to compute the moments quickly. I phrased the above in terms of an MCMC since those techniques are much more widely known.

Comment: Discretization is dangerous, in particular it is depending on parameterisation.

Comment: Do you say this because the regions of interest might change depending on the parameterization?